# InstallLocation is not written using standard installer?

Tags: windows, installation

I'm trying to get an application to pass the Windows 7 Software Logo Toolkit tests.

Everything works, just one part does not: The Toolkit test warns that my installation does not set the InstallLocation of my program.

I use the standard installer coming with VS2008SP, and I can't find no way to set the InstallLocation. I thought the installer should do this kind of stuff?

How do I get the installer to set the proper InstallLocation??

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VS2008 deployment project doesn't do this by default.  Fortunately you can do this through a custom action.

[Here's a blog](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/12/arpinstalllocation-for-visual-studio-setups) that includes a handy script that can be run as a post-build step in visual studio which inserts a type 51 custom action to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks - Just need to find out now how to have both this custom script and the code signing in the post build step.